# jQuery selector targeting JSON data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

Is there a jQuery selector I can use to target the value of an HTML5 data attribute, given the data is stored in JSON format?

For example, if I have something like `<button data-id="5">Some action</button>`, I can use `$("button[data-id='5']")` to select that button.

However, my data is stored as `<button data-properties='{"id":5,"name":"foo"}'>Some action</button>`. Is there a selector I can use for that, or do I have to use `.filter()` for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("button[data-properties*='\"id\":5']")
```

closest i can think about right now is this

*= translates to "attribute contains selector"

\ is to remove special meaning from " and consider them characters instead

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
$("button[data-properties]").each(function(){
    if($(this).data("properties").id == 5){
        //your action here
    }
});
```